# how to use signals to print every specific time and generate keyboard interrupt?

Tags: c, signals

I have the program below and I want to use signals to print the every 5 seconds, and handle keyboard interrupt like ctrl + c to terminate the process and ctrl + p to print the result.

```
int i=1;
while(i>0)
{
  i++;

  if(i%2==0)
  {
    printf("%d \n",i)
  }
}
```

Comment: On which operating system? The C standard does not know about signals (except with  `raise`)...

Comment: Whats wrong with using `sleep(5)`?

Comment: It is Linux Operating System

Comment: I am studying signals so I cannot use sleep, I must use signals.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience signal handling difficult to do reliably, prone to subtle race conditions and the like (and whoever thought EINTR was a good idea should be shot.) Then again I suppose I never really *got* the UNIX way of doing things.

My advise is to do as little work as humanly possible inside of the handlers themselves and to try to keep the signals masked anywhere you're not directly interested in them.

The following is my attempt at installing a SIGALRM handler and printing a message every 5 seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

// Raise a flag once the event occurs
volatile sig_atomic_t event;
void handler(int sig) { event = 1; }

int main(void) {
    sigset_t mask;

    // Install our alarm handler
    struct sigaction action = { 0 };
    action.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);

    // Mask out the alarm signal during normal operation to avoid races
    // and having to handle EINTR everywhere
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, &mask);

    // Here goes the main loop..
    for(;;) {
        // Set the alarm
        alarm(5);

        // Wait for the alarm to happen with the alarm signal unblocked.
        // Add whatever other I/O you're waiting for here
        pselect(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &mask);

        // Did we get woken up by an alarm signal?
        if(event) {
            event = 0;
            puts("Alarm!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

In your specific computationally-bound case I would suggest strategically polling the event flag from the loop instead of attempting to extract and print the present number from within the signal handler.

If you decide to go the latter route then beware that you cannot rely on being able to atomically read and write the value. Instead I would suggest a double-buffering scheme placing the two most recent values in a circular buffer with a (volatile sig_atomic_t) index pointing out the right slot. Oh, and you'll have to do the I/O through manual string manipulation and write() since printf is forbidden in a signal handler. The real kicker, though, is that you won't be able to synchronize with other standard output text in any sane fashion.

In essence using multithreading with a separate calculation thread is a far superior means of achieving the same end.